# How to deal with Angular Service when it makes dynamic URL as a constant?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6

I am writing Angular services for all my HTTP calls but the thing is that my URL's are dynamic and I am using ES6 and Babel. Now my problem is that whenever the application starts the Angular service seems to create constants for URL which don't get refreshed until I hit refresh on the browser and persist the data for the Dynamic URL. The code is as follows:-

```
import angular from 'angular';

class ProgramService {
    constructor($http, chpConstants, AuthService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.chpConstants = chpConstants;

        /*URL's to Query */
        this.PROGRAM_CREATION = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiURL.program_program_creation;
        this.PROGRAM_LISTING = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiContextBase + AuthService.getRole() + chpConstants.apiURL.program_view + '/' + AuthService.getId();
        this.PROGRAM_LOAD_PROGRAM = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiContextBase + AuthService.getRole() + chpConstants.apiURL.program_load_program;
    }

    /*Program Listing*/
    programListing() {
        var promise = null;
        if (!promise) {
            promise = this.$http.get(this.PROGRAM_LISTING).then(response => {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    }

    /*List of the Participants in a Program*/
    participantListing(program_ref_number) {
        var promise = null;
        if (!promise) {
            promise = this.$http.get(this.PROGRAM_PARTICIPANT_LISTING + "/" + program_ref_number + "/0/10").then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    };

    /*Program Load*/
    programLoad(program_ref_number) {
        var promise = null;
        if (!promise) {
            promise = this.$http.get(this.PROGRAM_LOAD_PROGRAM + "/" + program_ref_number).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    };

    /*Enroll Participant*/
    enrollParticipant(data) {
        var promise = null;
        if (!promise) {
            promise = $http.post(PROGRAM_ENROLL_PARTICIPANT, data).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
        return promise;
    };
}

ProgramService.$inject = ['$http', 'chpConstants', 'AuthService'];

export default angular.module('services.program-service', [])
    .service('ProgramService', ProgramService)
    .name;
```

Now I don't want to explicitly refresh the browser to get the service to re-instantiate. Since its a singleton, anything in the constructor is kinda fixed. Please tell me how can I preserve the dynamicity of the URL's as well as run the application.

Comment: Need to explain the concept of what `Dynamic URL` needs to do differently. Read this question several times and root problem is not clear. Where are the constants defined?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want these URL variables:

```
    /*URL's to Query */ 
    this.PROGRAM_CREATION = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiURL.program_program_creation;
    this.PROGRAM_LISTING = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiContextBase + AuthService.getRole() + chpConstants.apiURL.program_view + '/' + AuthService.getId();
    this.PROGRAM_LOAD_PROGRAM = chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants
```

to update as the chpConstants change? Why not do something like this:

```
var getProgramListingURL = function(){
   return chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiURL.program_program_creation;
}

programListing() {
    var promise = null;
    if (!promise) {
        promise = this.$http.get(getProgramListingURL()).then(response => {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    return promise;
}
```

Better Solution:

Make a service for these http calls:

```
yourApp.factory('API-Service', function($http, chpConstants) {

var api = {};
api.getProgramListing = function() {
  return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: chpConstants.baseURL + ":" + chpConstants.port + chpConstants.apiContextBase + AuthService.getRole() + chpConstants.apiURL.program_view + '/' + AuthService.getId();
  });
 };

 api.participantListing = function(program_ref_number){...};
 api.programLoad = function(program_ref_number){...}
 return api;
});
```

then inject your new API-Service into your controller and use it this way:

```
class ProgramService {
constructor($http, chpConstants, AuthService, API-Service) {

    API-Service.getProgramListing().then(function(response){...})
```

Comment: Do you suggest me to make a new function to do the job rather than keeping it inside the constructor?

Comment: Creating a new service is probably the best solution - I've updated my post.